# Relationship/Equality when one value is undefined.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

My issue is based on a common problem I find with singularities in functions, what happens if we have a relation like $y=f(x)$ but $x$ can take values not in the domain of $f$. $f(x)$ is undefined, does the scope of this relation imply that $y$ must also be undefined? Perhaps $y$ may take other values, as we are now out of the scope where all possible values of $(x,y)$ are in the space of tuples with elements in the domain $X_f$ and range $Y_f$

I cannot say that $Y$ has an element that is 'undefined' so how do I determine what the space of $y$ is, and what the exact set of tuples are that $x$ and $y$ form. How do I know whether my relation $y=f(x)$ holds in this case, or determine the value of $y$ when $f(x)$ becomes undefined?

Comment: In your example, $X$ is the domain, $Y$ is the range of the function.

Comment: *"what happens if we have a relation like $y=f(x)$ but $x$ can take values not in the domain of $f$."* The domain is *all* values that $x$ can take, so "what happens" for $x$ outside the domain is "nothing", because the situation doesn't arise. That said, it's often possible to *extend* the defn of a function over a broader domain (and perhaps a wider range). (Eg, extending trig functions to allow non-real arguments.) ... Anyway, in case I'm misunderstanding your intent, please provide a *specific* example of kind of function, domain, range, and out-of-domain $x$ you have in mind.

Comment: @Blue say, I have $y=f(x)$ and I can say that this is true for all $(x,y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are in the domain, what If I wanted to consider $x=0$, one one hand if $f(x)$ was defined at $x=0$ either the relation holds, or it does not, and if $y$ has to be equal to $f(x)$ then I know it does, however when everything becomes undefined, its not clear whether $y$ has to become undefined, or if I few the values for which the relation holds, as a subset and make $x$ and $y$ essentially able to vary freely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's no value called "undefined".** When we say that a syntactic *expression* is undefined, it just means that no definition has been given for it.

If $x$ is not in the domain of $f$, then the expression "$f(x)$" has no meaning, i.e. it is not defined. For such an $x$, the expression "$y=f(x)$" is also meaningless.

To formally specify a relation with an equation, we use [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate) to refer to a subset of a larger set of pairs, as in $R=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y:y=f(x)\}$. This only makes sense if $X$ is a subset of the domain of $f$. The [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) of $f$ is defined in this way with $X$ equal to the domain of $f$.

If we're sloppy and write something like $R=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R\times \Bbb R:y=\frac1x\}$, then a sympathetic reader will probably consider "$y=\frac1x$" to be false when $x=0$, so that $R$ does not include any pairs $(x,y)$ with $x=0$. This is equivalent to reading it as $\{(x,y)\in (\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})\times \Bbb R:y=\frac1x\}$ or as $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R\times \Bbb R:xy=1\}$.

Comment: So we basically make the relation at $x=0$ false, so what does that say about $y$, surely this allows $y$ to have any value at $x=0$ I could define that for $x=0$ then $y=4$ (as if I defined $f(x)$ as a piecewise) or I could define that $x$ and $y$ vary independently over the real numbers and have $X\times Y$ as a subset of $R^2$, after all that relation now doesn't hold true for all $x$? Or I could just leave it out of my set of possible values of $x$?

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing up the meanings of "equation" and "relation". "Relation" just means "set of $(x,y)$ pairs"; you can define such a set however you want just by saying which pairs you want it to include. But a relation **defined by an equation** of the form $y=f(x)$ will not include any $x$ values that are not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: So could I have a relation between $x$ and $y$ such that $x=1$ means $y=5$ and $x=-1$ means $y=9.34$, without necessarily having a relationship defined by an equation? Like we do with a piecewise function? for example $f(x)=x^2$ for $x≠ 2$ and $0$ for $x=2$

Comment: That's right. Any set of pairs you can describe is a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation). It can even include multiple pairs with same $x$ value.

Answer (score 0):

The thing called element $y$ here just does not exist at all. Because if such $y$ exists, then $y=f(x)$ for some $x$ in the domain of $f$, which is not the case.

Comment: Surely it become undefined implies that the relation sort of holds, for example why couldn't I have a set of tuples $x,y$ where $y=f(x)$ for a particular $f$, but have it as a subset of a larger space for which $x$ and $y$ can vary freely (essentially the whole of R^2), outside the subset, $f(x)$ is not defined, and the relation does not hold, could there be something similar here? Having $y$ just randomly not exist feels like we're enforcing a relationship that can't be true anyway, (there's no equality for undefined values). Does $y$ become undefined when $y=1/x$ and $x=0$?